# What's the best way to say "while *working on* Project X"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for "working on" in this sentence. I feel like there has to be a more concise way than to say "Joe has contributed a lot while working on Project X, Y and Z".  Joe has worked on many projects and I am trying to highlight a few specific ones he did very well on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One phrasing I might use is "while *participating in* Project X", especially if it were a public/semi-public/open-source project.  Other options include "as a part of Project X" and "as a member of Project X".

Comment: While @RegDwight's suggestion was more concise, I decided to accept @chaos' answer because he gave me several options to choose from and I can use some of them in other scenarios. At any rate, thank you both!

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you're looking for a more *concise* way, how about simply saying:

> Joe has contributed a lot **to** Project X, Y and Z.